# SWI-Prolog: Return all values except one

Tags: prolog

For the following SWI-Prolog program, I want to create a predicate that returns all values except a single one.
For example, return all males except **ahmed**.
How can I do that?

```
male(ahmed).
male(mohamed).
male(ali).
male(samir).
male(khalid).
```

Comment: `?- male(P),P\=ahmed.`

Comment: @CapelliC, oh please: `dif(P, ahmed), male(P)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to understand.

Do you want a predicate that return one single name of a (no Ahmed) male and, recalling it, via backtraching, another name, and another one... ?

I suppose that you can simply write

```
noAhmed(M) :-
  male(M),
  M \= ahmed.
```

Or do you want a predicate that return a list with all the (no Ahmed) male names?

In this case, you can write

```
noAhmedList(L) :-
  findall(M, (male(M), M \= ahmed), L).
```

Comment: Thanks. The one I need is noAhmed.